# Ubuntu 20.04 a couple of internet addresses does not relove

Tags: resolv.conf

Symptoms that i know of so far, cannot ping or visit with Firefox: hg.mozilla.org and ciscobinary.openh264.org - Ubuntu 20.04 always fails these two addresses and it starts after a week or two.
Reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 a couple of times, tried the mini.iso both with netplan and network-manager same issue.
Used synaptic to reinstall anything that starts with network, dhcp, dns and it did not help, even removed schnaps, no change...
Installed ubuntu-unity-desktop but that did not help either.
Have changed dns in network-manager-openvpn to clodflare, my isp and the two OpenVPNs dns-es that I use, well that did not help either.
But if I start Ubuntu 16.04 then it just works, dhcp, VPN-DNS-es, with or without connecting to a VPN, only dhcp or dns IPv4 cludflare, a mix of isp dns-4 and cloudflare dns-6, anything and it works.

Need help form someone who speaks DNS fluently

Comment: What is your question? More precisely, what actual problem are you trying to fix now? How did you configure the DNS servers?

Comment: Why am I not able to go to with Firefox or ping successfully hg.mozilla.org and ciscobinary.openh264.org after a week or so after installed Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Without me changing anything Ubuntu 20.04 just refuses to have anything to do with hg.mozilla.org and ciscobinary.openh264.org

Comment: Well I don't know what ciscobinary.openh264.org should contain, but it opens for me a page that only states "Resource not found". Tried Firefox, qutebrowser and elinks. One of those internet proxies showed me 404. So doesn't look like this is on your system. www.openh264.org is up'n running, as is the github page. https://hg.mozilla.org opens normally.